# Based on Array#reduce how does one identify the array item which matches best some specific constraints?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constraints, reduce

Basically what I'm trying to do is map this array and identify which objects satisfy a certain condition. The condition is:
Get an object that has the highest value of a+b and if you have two objects with the same value of a+b, get the one that has the highest value of c. What is the best way to do this? Maybe reduce?

```
   const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        a: 12,
        b: 75,
        c: 11,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        a: 65,
        b: 14,
        c: 32,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        a: 32,
        b: 23,
        c: 45,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        a: 22,
        b: 1,
        c: 3,
      },
    ];
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, what have you tried, and what fails?

Comment: I know. What I want is to understand the best way to do this. What I tried to do, and it worked, was to create a variable out of a map function and increment the values as the map function was sweeping.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)? There is no mention of anything to do with React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already a first naive [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which implements the OP's requirements and constraints almost literally does exactly what the OP is asking for.

In case one does not provide an [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) to the reducer, this reducing callback function gets passed the first two array items at its first invocation time. The function is supposed to return a value which, with any following iteration step, will be passed as the very functions 1st argument alongside the currently processed array item (which is the 2nd argument).

Thus for the OP's use case one just needs to implement the correct comparison which always ensures the expected return value ...

```js
function getItemWithHighestTotal(result, item) {
  const resultTotal = result.a + result.b;
  const itemTotal = item.a + item.b;
  return (
    ((resultTotal > itemTotal) && result) ||
    ((resultTotal < itemTotal) && item) ||
    ((result.c < item.c) && item) ||
    // OP did not define the clause where
    // even both `c` values are equal.
    result
  );
}

console.log(
  [{
    id: 1,
    a: 12,
    b: 75,
    c: 11,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    a: 65,
    b: 14,
    c: 32,
  }, {
    id: 3,
    a: 32,
    b: 23,
    c: 45,
  }, {
    id: 4,
    a: 22,
    b: 1,
    c: 3,
  }].reduce(getItemWithHighestTotal)
);
console.log(
  [{
    id: 1,
    a: 12,
    b: 75,
    c: 11,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    a: 65,
    b: 14,
    c: 32,
  }, {
    id: 3,
    a: 32,
    b: 23,
    c: 45,
  }, {
    id: 4,
    a: 22,
    b: 1,
    c: 3,
  }, {
    id: 5,
    a: 75,
    b: 12,
    c: 12,
  }].reduce(getItemWithHighestTotal)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @RoktSe ... since the OP brought up the matter her/himself, can the OP please elaborate more on how to handle items which are equal by every constraint?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop should work.  Loop through the array and if the current object's `a` + `b` is greater than a stored object, overwrite the stored object with the current loop object - checking `c` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop would be great

```js
const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        a: 12,
        b: 75,
        c: 11,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        a: 65,
        b: 14,
        c: 32,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        a: 32,
        b: 23,
        c: 45,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        a: 22,
        b: 1,
        c: 3,
      },
    ];
    
let index,
  cHigh = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER,
  total = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  const { a, b, c } = data[i];
  if (a + b > total) {
    total = a + b;
    index = i;
  } else if (a + b === total) {
    if (c > cHigh) {
      cHigh = c;
      index = i;
    }
  }
}
console.log(index);
console.log(data[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.reduce((res, obj) => {
  if (!res) return obj

  const { a: resA, b: resB, c: resC } = res
  const { a, b, c } = obj

  const sumRes = resA + resB
  const sum = a + b
  
  if(sum > sumRes) return obj
  else if (sum === sumRes) return c > resC ? obj : res
  else return res

}, null)
```

I think that's pretty understandable.

We initialize the first result with the first index. And we make a simple comparison game

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you'd like.

In the following, `acc` the accumulator is used to store the current known largest item. Each item in `data` is visited once, giving this a time complexity of `O(n)`.

If the `a + b` value of the current item `curr` is the same as that for the item in `acc`, then we compare the `c` values of the two items, and return the item with the larger `c`.

If the `a + b` value of the current item is larger than the value in `acc`, then we return `curr` to be the `acc` for the next item to be enumerated.

Otherwise we return `acc` (because `curr` must be less than `acc`).

Once enumeration of the items in `data` is complete, `reduce` will return the final value of `acc`, which will be the "largest" object.

```js
const data = [
      { id:1, a:12, b:75, c: 11 },
      { id:2, a:65, b:14, c: 32 },
      { id:3, a:32, b:23, c: 45 },
      { id:4, a:22, b:1,  c: 3  } ]

const largest = (arr) => 
    arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        switch(Math.sign((curr.a + curr.b) - (acc.a + acc.b))) {
            case 0:
                return curr.c > acc.c ? curr : acc
            case 1:
                return curr
            default:
                return acc
        }})

       
console.log(largest(data))
```